# How to use Extract on a Generic placeholder

Tags: typescript, generics

The `extend` guard on the bar class is not being enforced on the foo class.

```
Argument of type '"bar"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Extract<keyof T, string>'.
```

for both get and get2 calls in bar.

```js
class foo<T> {
    get(a: Extract<keyof T, string>) {
        return '';
    }
}

interface IAttrs {
    bar: boolean;
}

class bar<T extends IAttrs> extends foo<T>{

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.get('bar')
        this.get2('bar')
    }
 get2(a: Extract<keyof T, string>) {
        return '';
    }

}

class foobar extends foo<IAttrs>{

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.get('bar')
}

}
```

I expected the bar and foobar classes to both compile; but the bar class has the following error:

I'm using typescript 3.2.2

Comment: I don't think the compiler can resolve the conditional type `Extract<keyof T, string>` to something useful when `T` is still generic, even though you know that `keyof T` must include at least `"bar"`.  My suggestion is to change `Extract<keyof T, string>` to `Extract<keyof T | keyof IAttrs, string>` or even `(keyof T) & string`.

Comment: @jcalz if you add you comment as a solution I'll accept it. I wen with the ` (keyof T) & string`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that when `T` is an unresolved generic type parameter, the compiler does not (as of TS3.5 anyway) perform the sort of type analysis it would need to in order to recognize that `"bar"` is assignable to `Extract<keyof T, string>` even when `T` is constrained to extend `IAttrs`.  `Extract` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), and the compiler generally [defers most analysis of unresolved conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26931#issuecomment-419106316).  Perhaps this particular use case could be [filed in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) as a suggestion, but I doubt it would be given priority.

So we need to either use a resolved conditional type, or we need to use the unresolved type parameter in a non-conditional type.

- Resolved conditional type: Since `keyof T` includes all of `keyof IAttrs`, the type `keyof T` is equivalent to `keyof T | keyof IAttrs`.  So `Extract<keyof T | keyof IAttrs, string>` is equivalent to the problematic type.   But since `Extract` is [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types),  it will be evaluated as `Extract<keyof T, string> | Extract<keyof IAttrs, string>`.  The rightmost constituent is a resolved conditional type which will be eagerly evaluated to be just `"bar"`.  So now we have `Extract<keyof T, string> | "bar"`.  The unresolved conditional type is still there, but now `"bar"` is explicitly part of the union... and the error should go away.
- Unresolved non-conditional type: The `Extract` type was introduced in TS2.8 with conditional types.  It filters a union type with a constraint.  Before TS2.8 if we wanted to constrain a type like that, we just had to use [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types). It also used to be that intersections over unions were messy, and `("foo" | "bar") & ("bar" | "baz")` would evaluate to `("foo" & "bar") | ("foo" & "baz") | "bar" | ("bar" & "baz")`.  Nowadays though it gets [reduced](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18438) to just `"bar"`, as desired.  And luckily, even unresolved type parameters are analyzed in intersections... that is, if `X` is known to be assignable to both `A` and `B`, then `X` is known to be assignable to `A & B`.  So we can change `Extract<keyof T, string>` to `(keyof T) & string` and the error should also go away.

Let's look at some modified code that does both things:

```
class Foo<T> {
  // intersection
  get(a: keyof T & string) {
    return "";
  }
}

interface IAttrs {
  bar: boolean;
}

class Bar<T extends IAttrs> extends Foo<T> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.get("bar");
    this.get2("bar");
  }
  // resolved conditional
  get2(a: Extract<keyof T | keyof IAttrs, string>) {
    return "";
  }
}

class FooBar extends Foo<IAttrs> {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.get("bar");
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGtA9PtAJYB2ALgKYBOElw5x8pu0A5peQBRgBc0Aa0oBPeADNoKaADJoEctTJsAlFlZ5qnAK7VS0AET6A3KwC+2c9jJVqYsMErQAkgEFyCmDjwAjMNX7eiCCUYKQmlqCQMABCfqjQlAAeVKQAJjCu7rQYSSnpcIioGF7QwMzy1FoM8NRcqiV4EFoADjR1Jnh45AAWxBAAdBzc+r7U+sodnT19g5wATFwjfuOT5niE0JoQ8CAAbpSppcypxIzMYCCsQwt80ACiydT25EhCohJSAD6CIuLObh4ADRyBRKND1dSbbS6AzGMwWbDYSJQArwWLUBLJShpGAIZCZDzFVhlUgVKrkGp1NSdOQtNoTRE06YDIaLUYreHmIA)

And that all compiles with no error.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!